# Typo3 6.3 Userradialserach Extension doesnt work properly

Tags: typo3

at our homepage we provide a kind of "storelocator", which actually is a dealerlocator. The dealers that have been shown before are stored in a folder in the backend. They also have access to some frontenduser sites, to download for example pictures and logos.

Since google changed something in the policity the map doesnt work properly. does anyone know how to convert this

**plugin.tx_userradialsearch.settings.api.geocodeUrl = http://maps.google.de/maps/api/geocode/json**

into the new correct way with api key?

moreover the site doesnt show any of the Dealers that are registred. if you filter by the zipcode it simply doesnt show anything. the biggest problem i have is that the extension mentioned before is not findable on google or any other search engine.

since we are on Typo3 6.30 there are no other extensions i could use.

Comment: as there never was a version 6.3 of TYPO3 I assume your 6.30 may be 7.6.30 (current: 7.6.31), which ends free support in december!

Comment: Sie verwenden Version 6.2.30 - Copyright © 1998-2016 Kasper Skårhø

sry my bad its 6.2

Comment: 6.2.30 means no support (ELTS is at 6.2.38). I think you need more than an google-api update.

Answer (score 0):

The new GeoCoding-URL is just https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=...
The other parameters did not change.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. 
i did the change but the map is still grey and it says for development only.
moreover i have activated payment and added the correct key.
is there any support from google?

Comment: This is the geocoding URL, it is for finding geocoordinates for adresses (the first problem you described), not your map URL. Find the maps.googleapis.com-JS and add the key= there, too.

Comment: does filezilla have a search tool or something so i can search through my whole webspace? i cannot find any maps.googleapis.com-JS at my typo3 backend.

The GoogleMapsApi Plattform checker gives this Error:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false
This site doesn't seem to be using an API key. Keyless usage will soon be deprecated. Please set up and secure a key for your project.

Comment: search your file system by SSHing onto the system for "maps.googleapis.com". You might find it through the backend, too in Template -> Object Browser. But probably the path is hard coded in a file.